# Ruby on Rails: Concatenate two pieces of data into one column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, concatenation

I have 3 columns in my table projects. first_name, last_name, and fullname.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :first_name, :value => current_user.firstname %>
<%= f.hidden_field :last_name, :value => current_user.lastname %>
```

At the moment when the user saves a project, the first name and last name of user get saved into separate columns. I am now wanting for both the first name and last name to get saved to a column full name, so I can search on them later.

So if the name was

```
first_name = "Joe"
last_name = "Bloggs"
```

How would I get

```
fullname =  "Joe Bloggs"
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
<%=f.hidden_field :fullname, :value => :first_name + :last_name %>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm new to rails so please remember this when trying to help. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Now I have added this to my project model:

```
def set_fullname
    fullname = first_name + last_name
  end
```

and I now call this in my view:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :first_name, :value => current_user.firstname %>
<%= f.hidden_field :last_name, :value => current_user.lastname %>
<%= f.hidden_field :fullname, :value => @project.fullname %>
```

When I hit submit, and I check the logs the first and last names get saved to the table as usual, but the full name goes in blank. Can anyone see what the problem is?

**UPDATE2**

View:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :first_name, :value => current_user.firstname %>
<%= f.hidden_field :last_name, :value => current_user.lastname %>
<%= f.hidden_field :fullname, :value => @project.set_fullname %>
```

Project Model:

```
def set_fullname
    fullname = first_name + last_name
  end
```

When I try to access the page I get this error.

```
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: you can do concat operation in the controller before saving your user instead of keeping another hidden field in the view and sending it over to controller.

Comment: Can you show me how? I will post my controller for you to see

Comment: try this <%= f.hidden_field :fullname, :value => @project.set_fullname %>

Comment: I get the error `undefined method + for nil:NilClass` when I change to that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ruby code in your view is executed when the form is loaded, by that time there is no content in the form (if you create a new record). It would make sense to write similar code in javascript an map it to `onchange` event `first_name` and `last_name` text field.

Or you can do it on server side in your model, e.g:

```
class Person

  before :save, :set_fullname

  def set_fullname
    fullname = "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

`before :save` is executed each time when you're update your model

Anyway much cleaner solution would be to adjust your search query, this way you just duplicate information in your database.

While searching try something like this:

```
"first_name LIKE ? or last_name LIKE ? or concat(last_name, ', ', first_name) LIKE ?"
```

this SQL code might be database dependent, if you're using MySQL it's probably ok

Comment: What would I have in the view then?

Comment: in view you can call `person.fullname`

Comment: it's because undefined variable (empty variable) has value "nil" which is instance of NilClass. I've updated the answer, it's better to concatenate string that way, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

I know this was already answered by Tombart, but this could help someone else.

```
class Person

  before_create do
    self.fullname = "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

You can find more info on [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#callback-registration).